# Property implementation error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Im following this tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1845/ios-tutorial-how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-app-tutorial-part-2

I get the following errors:

```
1.Property implementation must have its declaration in interface "RWTDetailViewController"
2.Property "data" not found on object of type "id"
```

Here is my code:

```
#import "RWTScaryBugDoc.h"
#import "RWTScaryBugData.h"
#import "RWTUIImageExtras.h"
#import "RWTDetailViewController.h"

@interface RWTDetailViewController ()
- (void)configureView;
@end

@implementation RWTDetailViewController

#pragma mark - Managing the detail item
@synthesize picker = _picker;



- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }
}

- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.
    self.rateView.notSelectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"shockedface2_empty.png"];
    self.rateView.halfSelectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"shockedface2_half.png"];
    self.rateView.fullSelectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"shockedface2_full.png"];
    self.rateView.editable = YES;
    self.rateView.maxRating = 5;
    self.rateView.delegate = self;

    if (self.detailItem) {
        self.titleField.text = self.detailItem.data.title;
        self.rateView.rating = self.detailItem.data.rating;
        self.imageView.image = self.detailItem.fullImage;
    }
}

- (IBAction)titleFieldTextChanged:(id)sender
{
    self.detailItem.data.title = self.titleField.text;
}

#pragma mark UITextFieldDelegate
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark RWTRateViewDelegate

- (void)rateView:(RWTRateView *)rateView ratingDidChange:(float)rating
{
    self.detailItem.data.rating = rating;
}

- (IBAction)addPictureTapped:(id)sender {
    if (self.picker == nil) {
        self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        self.picker.delegate = self;
        self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        self.picker.allowsEditing = NO;
    }
    [self presentViewController:_picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    UIImage *fullImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    UIImage *thumbImage = [fullImage imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:CGSizeMake(44, 44)];
    self.detailItem.fullImage = fullImage;
    self.detailItem.thumbImage = thumbImage;
    self.imageView.image = fullImage;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self configureView];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

When I move my @synthesize into the interface-declaration, I the the following error: "Illegal interface qualifier"

Can anyone help me?

Here is my .h-file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RWTRateView.h"
@interface RWTDetailViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, RWTRateViewDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationBarDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet RWTRateView *rateView;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *titleField;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *detailDescriptionLabel;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImagePickerController *picker;

- (IBAction)addPictureTapped:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)titleFieldTextChanged:(id)sender;

@end
```

Comment: You don't need @synthesize any more. Just define the @property. Where is your propery definition for `data`

Comment: Why you need to move `@synthesize` to `@interface` ?

Comment: @synthesise is meant to be in implementation....

Comment: @Paulw11: But he is using synthesize in the tutorial? So I should remove synthesize? Where should I define the property?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: What do you mean?

Comment: I imagine you're missing an import statement for whatever is the type of `self.detailItem`

Comment: That tutorial is 4 years old. Find a better one?  The picker property should be defined I the .h file

Comment: @KerrM: Can you be more specific? :)

Comment: Perhaps add your RWTdetailViewController.h to your question

Comment: Why do I get the error Property "data" not found on object of type "id"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error description is self explanatory, you need to declare *picker* as a property in interface(.h) file before you move to implementation(.m) file and synthesize it. However you don't need to synthesize properties anymore but if you do that is also fine.
One more thing, you missed the part from tutorial in which writer has declared this property in .h file already. You can have a look again or add this line to *RWTDetailViewController.h*

> @property (strong, nonatomic) UIImagePickerController *picker;

**EDIT**
For second error you are declaring *detailItem* as an object of type *id*, however writer is using a custom class *RWTScaryBugDoc* in which he should be having a property named *data*. That's why you are getting the error as property *data* doesn't belong to *id* type. You may want to download the sample code at the end of tutorial and cross check the missing points.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you help me with my second error I get? "2.Property "data" not found on object of type "id"

Answer (score 0):

You just need to declare your property first. So in the interface (h file or top of your m file), add:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong)UIImagePickerController *picker;
```

The `@synthetise` need to stay in the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You declare self.detailItem as Id. Id is no class and so it has no attribute, but you try to access self.detailItem.data.... This is not possible.
I can't help you to fix this, because there are so many logical erros in your code, that 99% of it makes no sense for me.